# Disable a web extension toolbar button except for specific domains

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on

I'm writing a web extension at the moment that should have a toolbar button, but should be disabled except for a handful of frequently visited sites. However, I can't find a way to indicate to the browser that it should enable the toolbar button selectively based on domain matching.

While I can restrict the `content_scripts` section using the `"matches": [...]` syntax, the background script will (of course) load universally, but there [does not appear to be a way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) to specify in the `manifest.json` that there should be domain restrictions.

Alternatively, is there a simple way to tell the browser to disable a toolbar button (or swap out its graphic) unless the active tab's location matches a domain for running the extension's actions are meaningful? Looking at something like NoScript this should be possible, but I can't find any mention, let alone example, of how that might be done [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions).

Comment: Have you tried to use a pageAction? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction

Comment: I have not. I'll see where that gets me, but I'd still very much like to keep that button in the button bar instead of forcing it into the url bar (a place that is already horribly crowded with things like pocket and the ridiculous "..." button)